# Angular ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Learning the AngularJS. Trying to change an example from tutorial. Need ng-init value be equals to the value transmitted from script function. How it can be done? Code is below:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
        <div ng-app="mainApp"  ng-controller="clickController">
            <p>Total click: {{  click.clickCounter() }}</p>
            <button ng-click="count = count+1" 
              ng-init="count=click.clickCounter()">Click Me!</button>
        </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
        </script>
    </body>

    <script>
        var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

        mainApp.controller('clickController', function($scope) {
            $scope.click = {
                count: 15,
                clickCounter: function() {
                    var foo;
                    foo = $scope.click;
                    return foo.count;
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Problem is with transfering the value of click.clickCounter() to ng-click.

Comment: what this code should do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You issue is your are creating a new `count` variable on the root of your scope.

Your count vaiable if `$scope.click.count` however the `ng-init` ang `ng-click` are creating and updating `$scope.count`.

this fixes the issue

```
<button ng-click = "click.count = click.count+1" ng-init="click.count=click.clickCounter()">Click Me!</button>
```

EDIT: If you add `{{count}}` inside your app you will see the scope variable it is creating. One of the double edged swords of Angular is if you define variables in your view that don't exist on your scope Angular will create and add them to the scope for you.

EDIT 2: Your `ng-init` is obsolete. Seeing as you already created a `count` property of your `$scope.click` object it is already initialized and has a value.

Also see fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yjwskkat/